How to enforce generic parameter to be of type u8, u16, u32, or u64 in Rust?
I'm trying to write a function in Rust that should accept a generic parameter T, but I want to enforce T to be one of the unsigned integer types (u8, u16, u32, or u64). Additionally, I want to restrict T to support certain bitwise operations such as AND (&) and OR (|), as well as bitwise assignment operators (&= and |=).
Here's what I've tried so far:
fn test<T>(mut x: T)
where
    T: std::fmt::Display
        + BitAnd<u8, Output = T>
        + BitOr<u8, Output = T>
        + BitAndAssign<u8>
        + BitOrAssign<u8>
        + std::cmp::PartialOrd<u8>,
{
    if x >= 2 {
        x &= 4;
    }
    println!("{}", x);
}


However, this implementation only works when T is u8. When I try to include other types like u16, u32, or u64, it fails to compile.
What would be the correct way to enforce T to be one of these specific unsigned integer types and support the required bitwise operations?
Thank you for your help!

If you want to have it work with all the unsigned types, use T instead of u8 in the bounds.
Then you can't use literal numbers directly in the code because it's not guaranteed that T can be constructed from a literal number, so add a T: From<u8> bound and explicit conversions:
fn test<T>(mut x: T)
where
    T: std::fmt::Display
        + BitAnd<T, Output = T>
        + BitOr<T, Output = T>
        + BitAndAssign<T>
        + BitOrAssign<T>
        + std::cmp::PartialOrd<T>
        + From<u8>,
{
    if x >= T::from (2) {
        x &= T::from (4);
    }
    println!("{}", x);
}

Playground
This will also work with any type T that satisfies the constraints, not limited to u8 … u64 (notably it will work for usize). This shouldn't be an issue in practice, but if you really want to limit yourself to a set of type simply add a marker trait that you only implement for the types you want:
trait Marker{}

impl Marker for u8 {}
impl Marker for u16 {}
impl Marker for u32 {}
impl Marker for u64 {}

fn test<T>(mut x: T)
where
    T: std::fmt::Display
        + BitAnd<T, Output = T>
        + BitOr<T, Output = T>
        + BitAndAssign<T>
        + BitOrAssign<T>
        + std::cmp::PartialOrd<T>
        + From<u8>
        + Marker,
{
    if x >= T::from (2) {
        x &= T::from (4);
    }
    println!("{}", x);
}



If this is part of a library, one can prevent downstream code from implementing Marker for their own types by making Marker a sealed trait.

why would implementing Marker Trait would enforce this ? any ressources to help  me figure it out.

@dieri T: Marker enforces that T is unsigned simply because Marker (there's nothing special about the name, you can call it whatever you want) is only implemented for the unsigned types. See impl blocks right after the trait definition.

Oh I understand, however why the rest are necessary ? As Marker is only implemented for u8…u64, should just put where T Marker is not sufficient ?

@dieri You could make it work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3c9964d00cce254ee48d5c669397d891

And why not use From instead of From, and why even use From trait in the first case ?

Because 2 and 4 don't have type T, so we need some way to tell the compiler that they can be converted to T

Also T: From<T> is trivially true for all T and so completely useless as a bound.

If you don't mind an external (but small) dependency, you can use the funty crate to give you a trait for unsigned types. You will also need From<u8> because things like x >= 2 don't work for generic x, even when bound by a trait only implemented for numbers. For example, this compiles for all unsigned types (and only them):
use funty::Unsigned;

fn test<T: Unsigned + From<u8>>(mut x: T) {
    if x >= T::from(2) {
        x &= T::from(4);
    }
    println!("{}", x);
}


Thanks however I'd like to do it by myself as I am currently learning rust

@dieri That might have been good to mention in the question. In that case jmb's answer is what you need.
